# Update Firestore document ID and auth email with same method

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am teaching myself how to code by building a little project site but have been stuck for a few days trying to figure out how to update users' profile and account information. I am able to figure out how to retrieve and display the information but am having difficulty in getting them to update it

Goal:

1. Update the account email that they use at login
2. Update their full name stored in firestore (I figured this one out)
3. Update the document id of their user in Firestore (which is used for their profile slug)

So far I have been able to figure out how to display all three in the form fields, but only how to update the user's full name in Firestore with point 1 and 3 still escaping me.

For Goal 2 I used "Update a document" from Firestore documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data which works successfully

For updating user email I attempted to use the update email method from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

[Screenshot of document in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk8Zw.png)

```
<template>

  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-layout justify-center align-center v-if="profile">

      <v-flex xs12 sm8 md8 style="max-width: 600px">
        <v-card >
          <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
            <v-toolbar-title>Profile</v-toolbar-title>               
          </v-toolbar>


          <v-flex class="ml-3 my-4">
            <v-avatar size="75px" class="mr-2" >
                        <img
                        class="img-circle elevation-2 "
                        src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vuetifyjs/docs/dev/static/doc-images/lists/1.jpg"
                        >
                    </v-avatar>

                    <v-btn color="primary" >Upload</v-btn>
                    <v-btn>Delete</v-btn> 
          </v-flex>

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-form>
              <v-text-field 
                prepend-icon="person" 
                required 
                v-model="profile.fullname" 
                name="fullname" 
                label="Full Name" 
                type="text">
              </v-text-field>
              <v-text-field 
                v-if="user" 
                prepend-icon="email" 
                required 
                v-model="user.email" 
                name="email" 
                label="Email" 
                type="text">
              </v-text-field>
              <v-text-field 
                v-model="this.profile.id" 
                hint="Create a unique URL for your profile. Many people use their first and last name. <br> [Ex: reel.ly/misha.collins]"
                persistent-hint
                id="username"  
                prepend-icon="link" 
                name="username" 
                required
                label="Profile URL " 
                type="text">
              </v-text-field>
            </v-form>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <!-- <p class="red-text center" v-if="feedback">{{ feedback }}</p> -->
            <v-btn flat @click.native="updatemyProfile" color="primary">Save</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
        <!-- <v-card style="margin-top: 30px" class="elevation-2">
          <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
            <v-toolbar-title>Billing</v-toolbar-title>               
          </v-toolbar>
          <v-card-text>
            <v-form>

            </v-form>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer> 
          <p class="red-text center" v-if="feedback">{{ feedback }}</p> 
           <v-btn flat @click.native="updateBilling" color="primary">Update Account</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card> -->
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>

</template>

<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import slugify from 'slugify'

export default {
    name: 'Account',
    data () {
      return {
        user: null,
        profile: null,
        feedback: null,
        docid: null
      }

    },

    created () {
      let ref = db.collection('users')        

        // get current profile to list full name
        ref.where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.profile = doc.data(),
                this.profile.id = doc.id
            })
        })

        // get current user to list email
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
              this.user = user

              // console.log(this.user)
          } else {
              this.user.uid = null
          }
        })


    },
    methods: {
      updatemyProfile() {
        // working to change fullname but not document id
        let ref = db.collection('users')  

        // get current profile
        ref.where('user_id', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.profile = doc.data(),
                this.profile.id = doc.id
            })
        })

        var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.profile.id)

        return docRef.update({
          id: this.profile.id, // this is adding an id field and assigning this.profile.id value to it instead of updating the document id of the user
          fullname: this.profile.fullname
        })

        // update email address
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
          user.updateEmail(this.user.email).then(function() {
            console.log("success")
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // An error happened.
        })
        }
      }
}

</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this bit of code at the end of your function:

```
    var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.profile.id)

    return docRef.update({
      id: this.profile.id,
      fullname: this.profile.fullname
    })

    // update email address
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
      user.updateEmail(this.user.email).then(function() {
        console.log("success")
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
    })
```

You're returning early from the function with the `return` keyword after you call the `update()` method, which means that any code after that in the function (the update of email address) won't get run.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, removed!

Though the update email code still does not update the email in Firebase and still unable to update the document id of the user in the firestore. Any tips on these would be much appreciated!

Comment: If I change the email only and submit I get a Post 400 error. 
If I only try to change the Profile URL field as soon as I type a letter into the field the console now throws two errors. 1. [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "input": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null" and 2. TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null.

I am still able to upload the Full Name field though

Comment: What you have now is some other problem that's not related to the first, and also not related to Firebase.  Probably best to ask another question and describe what's going on now.